# Store form Image elements in a array

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I need some help with storing image form elements in a array.
I have tried to use As Object/Variant and I've run out of logical options to try

As you can see below, the names of the images are I_Monday, I_Tuesday etc.

Current code:

```
Dim I_Day(0 To 4) As Image
I_Day(0) = I_Monday
I_Day(1) = I_Tuesday
I_Day(2) = I_Wednesday
I_Day(3) = I_Thursday
I_Day(4) = I_Friday
```

The elements with be accessed in a for loop.

```
For i = 0 To 4
  If sht.Cells(nameRow, weekNum + i).Value = "Pass" Then
    I_Day(i).BackColor = RGB(0, 255, 0)
  ElseIf sht.Cells(nameRow, weekNum + i).Value = "Fail" Then
    I_Day(i).BackColor = RGB(255, 0, 0)
  Else
    I_Day(i).BackColor = RGB(0, 0, 255)
  End If
Next i
```

Thanks for any help.

Edit: Should probably mention the error message:
Run time error 91:
Object variable or with block not set

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because they are objects, you need to use `Set` when assigning them:

```
Dim I_Day(0 To 4) As Image
Set I_Day(0) = I_Monday
Set I_Day(1) = I_Tuesday
Set I_Day(2) = I_Wednesday
Set I_Day(3) = I_Thursday
Set I_Day(4) = I_Friday
```

Comment: a bit off topic, but wouldn't the correct format be `IPicture` instead of `Ìmage` ?

Comment: Not if you're storing the image **control**, rather than the picture it contains.